# Why encrypting Web.config file works without supplying a keyContainerName?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config, web-config-encryption

So using the aspnet_regiis.exe util I have done the following

```
//Create the container
aspnet_regiis -pc MyRSAKey -exp

//Write key to file
aspnet_regiis -px MyRSAKey MyRSAKey.xml

//Install the key into a machine-level RSA key provider.
aspnet_regiis -pi MyRSAKey MyRSAKey.xml

//Grant access to the contrainer
aspnet_regiis -pa "MyRSAKey" "NT Authority\Network service"
```

Now I thought that to use this key I needed to add this to the web.config file

```
<configProtectedData defaultProvider="MyProviderName">
<providers>
  <add
    name="MyProviderName" 
    type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider,  System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"           
    keyContainerName="MyRSAKey"
    useMachineContainer="true" />
</providers>
```

Now when I run this command it works:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "sectiomName" "pathToConfigFile" -prov "MyProviderName"
```

The thing is that it works no matter what value I have for keyContainerName. Or even when I take keyContainerName out of the config file completely it still works suggesting that it's not actually using the key I generated and installed.

Also visual studio 2010 doesn't even recognise keyContainerName (or useMachineContainer) saying that the 'keyContainerName' name is not allowed.

What's going on here?

Comment: Why do you use [multiple exclamation marks](http://wiki.lspace.org/wiki/Multiple_exclamation_marks)?

Comment: because he's conveying exacerbated vexation!!!

Answer (score 0):

To tackle the two questions out of order:

> Visual Studio 2010 doesn't even recognise `keyContainerName` (or `useMachineContainer`) saying that the 'keyContainerName' name is not allowed.
>
> What's going on here?

I haven't decompiled the relevant configuration section class to check, but I observe that `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` has properties `KeyContainerName` and `UseMachineContainer`, so it seems to be that a) when parsing a `providers/add` element it uses reflection to set corresponding fields on the instance of `type`; and b) whoever wrote the XML schema which VS2010 uses to validate `.config` files forgot an `<xsd:anyAttribute>` tag.

(FWIW this question is what I was hoping to answer when I discovered your question, which ranks highly in Google for `keycontainername attribute is not allowed`).

---

> The thing is that it works no matter what value I have for keyContainerName. Or even when I take keyContainerName out of the config file completely it still works suggesting that it's not actually using the key I generated and installed.

When you say "it works", I think you mean that `aspnet_regiis -pef` doesn't give an error. However, if you try to access the protected configuration section in your code I bet it will complain unless you used the correct `keyContainerName`.

I suspect that if the name doesn't correspond to a known key container it creates a new one, but I haven't attempted to verify this.